# How to Pass Mutliple data to codeigniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

I am working on a template, i need to pass database results into jquery datatables in view page. now the problem is there is also a template named located at `application/view/admin/layout.php` that we use globally it includes head, footers, sidebars, and other global library.
now the issue is i am not able to pass this template to controller.

Belwo is the my controller (application/controllers/admin/Applications.php

```
       <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Applications extends MY_Controller {
        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();

        }

        public function appindex(){
            $data['view'] = 'admin/dashboard/index';
            $this->load->model('admin/App_model');
            $result['data']=$this->App_model->applists();
            $this->load->view('admin/layout', $data, $result);

        }               
            }

?>
```

Below is the my model ( application/models/admin/App_model.php

```
    <?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class App_model extends CI_Model{

    public function applists(){

            $query=$this->db->query("select * from tblapps");
            return $query->result();

        }       
}
?>
```

this is the code for my  global file (layout.php) view

```
            <section id="container">
            <!--header start-->
            <header class="header white-bg">
                <?php include('include/navbar.php'); ?>
            </header>
            <!--header end-->
            <!--sidebar start-->
            <aside>
                <?php include('include/sidebar.php'); ?>
            </aside>
            <!--sidebar end-->
            <!--main content start-->
            <section id="main-content">
                <div class="content-wrapper" style="min-height: 394px; padding:15px;">
                    <!-- page start-->
                    <?php $this->load->view($view);?>
                    <!-- page end-->
                </div>
            </section>
            <!--main content end-->
            <!--footer start-->
            <footer class="main-footer">
                <strong>Copyright © 2018 <a href="#">Indian I Services</a></strong> All rights
                reserved.
            </footer>
            <!--footer end-->
        </section>
```

this is my index.php in view page where i am passing database query results.

```
 <tbody>
            <?php
                 $i=1;              
                foreach($data as $row)
            {
               echo "<tr>";
               echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$row->app_id."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$row->firstname."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$row->email."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row->sdate."</td>";
               echo "</tr>";
               $i++;
             }
            ?>              
            </tbody>
```

its giving me error,

> A PHP Error was encountered
>       Severity: Notice
>       Message: Undefined variable: data
>       Filename: applications/index.php
>       Line Number: 42

if i use this code in controller - it shows just table. but how to include that template file so it can show all header, footer, and menus.

```
    <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Applications extends MY_Controller {
        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();

        }

        public function appindex(){
            $this->load->model('admin/App_model');
            $result['data']=$this->App_model->applists();
            $this->load->view('admin/applications/index', $result);

        }               
            }

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Pass both `view` and `data` results like this :*

```
public function appindex()
{
    $result['view'] = 'admin/dashboard/index';
    $this->load->model('admin/App_model');
    $result['data'] = $this->App_model->applists();
    $this->load->view('admin/layout', $result);
}
```

Your view should be like this :

```
<section id="main-content">
            <div class="content-wrapper" style="min-height: 394px; padding:15px;">
                <!-- page start-->
                <?php if ( !empty($view))
                {
                   $this->load->view($view);
                }?>
                <!-- page end-->
            </div>
</section>
```

This is your `data` part

```
<tbody>
  <?php
  if (! empty($data))
  {
    $i=1;              
    foreach($data as $row)
    {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row->app_id."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row->firstname."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row->email."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row->sdate."</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      $i++;
    }
  }
  ?>              
</tbody>
```

For more : https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view

Comment: let me test sir.

Comment: Thanxx Pradeep, That Worked . and also thankyou for the documentation, will learn

Comment: pleasure is mine, happy coding, pls do upvote my answer too sir

Answer (score 1):

Store both your data and result in $data['data'] and $data['result']
And pass it to view
In view. get data using $result and $data

Comment: Hello sir its not my question

Comment: Thanks, Well its been solved. your suggestions was right. but pradeep answred with demonostration. thank to everybody

Comment: My pleasure sir